# xml to CSV - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, xml, csv

```
    for tm in teamtree.iter('team_members'):
```

I'm trying to output these fields into a CSV using the above function.
The xml data is stored in a variable called (projectDetJoined)

I'm getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "10Other.py", line 481, in <module>
parseXMLTaskDetails()
  File "10Other.py", line 355, in parseXMLTaskDetails
taskcid = (t.find('cid').text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The items exist in the xml data.

Any ideas why its not finding it? I have a similar function that is structured the same way but does work.

Comment: In your XML the `team_members` element does not have subelements like `cid` etc. It has `item` subelements. Perhaps you meant `for tm in teamtree.iterfind('team_members/item')`. If your CSV headers didn't have different case for some items, you could've just mapped `tm.findtext` over them in the for-loop body to extract the values for writing. Don't reopen the file all the time for append, but move the XML extraction to the with-block that initially creates the file and csv-writer. The final `csvfile.close()` is also redundant.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Optimized the code as per your suggestions. Thanks a lot. Didn't know what iterfind was til now.  Not sure why the down votes on the question. But anyway, this worked fine and now I know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**Ilja Everilä's** comment solved my problem.

> In your XML the team_members element does not have subelements like
>   cid etc. It has item subelements. Perhaps you meant for tm in
>   teamtree.iterfind('team_members/item'). If your CSV headers didn't
>   have different case for some items, you could've just mapped
>   tm.findtext over them in the for-loop body to extract the values for
>   writing. Don't reopen the file all the time for append, but move the
>   XML extraction to the with-block that initially creates the file and
>   csv-writer. The final csvfile.close() is also redundant.